# Obtaining a particular 3d view in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to achieve the following plot, with the indicated perspective and the axis lines centered:
[image]

I've played around with several **view** options and I'm just not able to reproduce the figure. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,font=\footnotesize]
     \begin{axis}[view={45}{110},axis lines = center,colormap/greenyellow,xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},zlabel={$z$}]
      \addplot3[surf,samples=40,domain=-4:4,y domain=-3:3]{-2*x+3*y+6};
     \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I doubt there is a way around drawing the axis manually. You can set layers for the different parts. I'm not sure if the intersections can be calculated through LaTeX or whether you have to do them yourself. (I'm assuming the former.)